# Django - Excel Calculate the total of method value

Tags: python, django

I created a data model that user upload excel file and calculate the row and column

```
class Data(models.Model):
    """ Model of Data"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.document)

    def amount(self):
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(self.document.name)
        worksheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

        row_count = worksheet.nrows
        print(row_count)
        column_count = worksheet.ncols
        print(column_count)

        total_col_row = row_count * column_count

        # print payments
        payments = total_col_row * 9

        return payments
```

how to get the total amount if user enter for example a 3 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add `amount` as a `DecimalField` of your model, and calculate it after creating your object, thanx to `post_save` signal.
Then add a static method that simply sums all your amounts.

```
     from django.db.models import Sum
     from django.dispatch import receiver

     class Data(models.Model):
                """ Model of Data"""
                user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                document = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
                uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
                amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

                def __str__(self):
                    return str(self.document)

              @property
               def total_amount():
                    return Data.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('amount '))['amount __sum']

                def calculate_amount(self):
                    wb = xlrd.open_workbook("documents/%Y/%m/%d"+self.document.name)
                    ...

  @receiver(post_save, sender=Data)
   def data_amount_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   instance.amount= instance.calculate_amount()
   instance.save()
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the code but new error exist, it show FileNotFoundError when I tried to upload a new file

Comment: Well, you upload your excel to `upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d"`, so you should open the workbook from there too:` wb = xlrd.open_workbook("documents/%Y/%m/%d"+self.document.name)`

Comment: I change but still find error it requires to upload the files before to save. I remove the def save: function it can read the file but the amount didn't save to db.

Comment: the total_amount() function return 0

Comment: I updated the answer with the proper logic: Upload > Save Data object > Calculate, now your static method should give you the result

Comment: self is not defined show in self.calculate_amount(). but when I change to instance.amount = instance.calculate_amount(). delay to load and uploading 3 files

Comment: Surely, in the post_save we work with instance not self. What about the delay to load and uploading 3 files ? not so clear

Comment: when I upload files it takes 15 seconds to load and then show page isn't working need to refresh the page so the files show with 3 uploaded files. but only 1 file I upload

Comment: Is your question about the calculate is solved ? If so you may close this question, as it appear your new point is about the upload itself, not the calculate method

Comment: Yes it's show the total of calculate method. I think the problem now is in upload I will figure out it first and ask question again here in stackoverflow. Thanks for your time to help me.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Can you please mark it as an answer and solved

Comment: the problem is not in upload, but in signals it send triple. because of this line of code --> instance.save().. when I remove it upload ok. I think need another logic

Comment: If you want your field to be calculated on creation, you can use: def perform_create(self, serializer), under your DataSerializer as shown here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/, and use the same code of your signal